# Transaction Firestore Not Executing

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having some issues with writing via transactions to Firestore. I'm trying to update all of the documents in a collection that belongs to an user by adding the otherUserID to the user's array of the document. The user's array of the documents are not updating, and after some debugging I found the issue is that the code below 'Breakpoint 2' executes before 'Breakpoint 1' meaning the transaction update never takes place since the dataList was still empty.

But from the way the code is written, shouldn't the code within the the **forEach** hence 'Breakpoint 1' complete first?

```
Future<void> updateData(User myUser, String otherUserID) async {
  List<Data> dataList = [];
  QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> otherDataQuery =
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('data')
             .where('userID', isEqualTo: myUser.userID)
          .get();
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction(
    (transaction) async {
      otherDataQuery.docs.forEach(
        (document) async {
          Data oldData = Data.fromMap(
            document.data(),
          );
          DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await transaction.get(
            dataRef.doc(oldData.ID),
          );
          Data thisData =
              Data.fromMap(snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
          thisData.users!.add(otherUserID);
          dataList.add(thisData);
          print('Breakpoint 1');
          print(dataList.length);
        },
      );
      print('Breakpoint 2');
      print(dataList.length);
      for (var i = 0; i <= dataList.length - 1; i++) {
        await transaction.update(
          dataRef.doc(dataList[i].ID),
          {'usersList': dataList[i].users},
        );
      }
    },
    timeout: Duration(seconds: 10),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `forEach` loop and with a `for` loop.

Async `forEach` is a little bit different from async `for` loop

```
otherDataQuery.docs.forEach(
  (document) async {
    Data oldData = Data.fromMap(document.data());
    print('TEST 1');
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await transaction.get(
      dataRef.doc(oldData.ID),
    );
    print('TEST 2');
    Data thisData = Data.fromMap(snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
    thisData.users!.add(otherUserID);
    dataList.add(thisData);
    // print('Breakpoint 1');
    // print(dataList.length);
  },
);
print('TEST 3');
// for (var i = 0; i <= dataList.length - 1; i++) { ... }
```

Lets assume otherDataQuery contains 3 docs, the above function should print as below.

```
TEST 1
TEST 1
TEST 1
TEST 3
TEST 2
TEST 2
TEST 2
```

So, Test 3 (your for loop) will be called before Test 2 (transaction.get()) is completed. Therefore, `print(dataList.length)` will print `0`. So instead, use a `for` loop.

So Instead, try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < otherDataQuery.size; i++) {
  Data oldData = Data.fromMap(otherDataQuery.docs[i].data());
  DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await transaction.get(
    dataRef.doc(oldData.ID),
  );
  Data thisData = Data.fromMap(snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
  thisData.users.add(otherUserID);
  dataList.add(thisData);
  print('Breakpoint 1');
  print(dataList.length);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter! I'll follow-up to see if things work out on my side.